# Arduino battery capacity selection based on the current measurements

Tags: arduino-mega, battery, current, solar

I'm sorry for this stupid question...
I'm not an electronic/electric expert..
In order to select the battery capacity as well as the solar panel I'm measuring the Arduino current consumption.
So, I connected my multimeter (in line) (I rotated the selector on 200mA) and I'm able to see the values that are:

- around 85mA for  few seconds (around 8seconds) when the system works;
- around 0.38 mA during the remaining 52 seconds when the system is in sleep mode.
  I'll enable my system around 8s for each 15minutes (basically 4 times for hour)

In order to have a general idea, I would like to use a site like this https://www.digikey.it/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-battery-life

Now, It's not clear for me how can I use the retrieved values:
Do I calculate the current consuming in 1h?

The values that I obtained are related to the current consumed for a second?

What I have to punt into the field "Device Consumption" on the linked web-site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two current values and the approximate time those currents run for.  From that you can calculate the *average* current.

If you have 8 seconds "on" and (15*60-8) 892 seconds "off" that gives you:

```
(85 * 8) + (0.38 * 892)
------------------------
         900
```

Which comes out as 1.13mA on average at any point in time (that's a simple ratio calculation - the times don't matter, only the ratio between them).

Over the course of 1 hour you will consume around 1.13mA on average, which is 1.13mAh.

To run for 24 hours you will need 1.13*24 = 27.2mAh. To run for a week it's 27.2*7 = 190mAh.

The calculations, as you can see, once you have the average current are pretty simple.

Of course you need to "derate" the results since batteries *never* hold the stated amount - that is both a "theoretical maximum" under ideal conditions, which degrades over time (as you will know when your phone battery starts dying too soon), plus you *never* run a battery completely flat.  Personally I like to double the capacity to err on the safe side.

You also know that you need to charge the batteries with at least an average of 1.13mA from your solar cells. That means working out what ratio of the time will be available for actual charging (daylight with good sun brightness) and calculating how much current you will need to generate during that time to allow the system to run in the dark.

Comment: How you obtained 1.13mA?
((85 * 8) + (0.38 * 892))/900 = 38.42
Do I missed some others calculation?

Comment: @Safari 85*8 = 680. 0.38*892 = 338.96. 680+338.96 = 1018.96. 1018.96/900=1.13217...

Comment: :D :D :D Yeah! Sorry... wrong copy and paste :s